# Dealing with Android devices that lie about having a camera flash?

Tags: android, flash, camera, led, nexus-7

I'm building a flashlight app and I've learned that when I call

`this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)`,

the Nexus 7 returns true and when asking for the `FlashModes()` the size is 1 and the option is called "off." So when I check whether or not flash exists on devices, if the device lies about it, I can run into trouble. I've added `!android.os.Build.MODEL.equals("Nexus 7")` to my if statement to prevent crashing my app while testing on my Nexus 7.

If there are other devices that lie about having a flash, my app will likely crash on them. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement a double check

after calling

```
this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)
```

check if

```
getSupportedFlashModes() returns null
```

if no

check if

```
flash modes only contains one entry  "off"
```

Comment: Will every device that doesn't have a flash but hasSystemFeature returns true have a flash mode of "off" while any device that DOES have a flash will not have a mode called "off"?

Comment: @ZeekAran edited the answer, check for length odf supported flash modes and value=off

Comment: @ZeekAran the only cases i know off, is either getSupportedFlashModes() return null (e.g. for some chinese phones) or have a single entry "off" (like for nexus 7).

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

I am now using:

if (!hasSystemFeature)

else

p = cam.getParameters();
if (p.getSupportedFlashModes() != null) {
if (p.getSupportedFlashModes().size() == 1) {
if (p.getSupportedFlashModes().get(0).equals("off")) {

And this properly checks my deceitful Nexus 7.